# Sums of p-th powers of first N positive integers equal a p-th power of an integer

Tags: number-theory, open-problem

I am looking for $(p, N)$ where $p$, $N$ are integers greater than 1 and

$${\sum_{n=1}^{N}n^{p}}=M^{p}$$

where $M$ is an integer.

$p=2$, $N=24$ leading to $M=70$ is the Cannonball problem, and it was shown that if $p=2$ then $N=24$.

Do we know of any other $(p, N)$ that satisfy this, or how can we prove that $p=2$, $N=24$ is the only case?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. FYI, see [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula).

Comment: @JohnOmielan Unless I am missing something, Faulhaber's formula does not answer the question.  I know that (for example) $~1^3 + \cdots + 4^3 = 10^2~$ but this doesn't guarantee that a solution will exist with $p = 3.$  Further, it leaves higher values of $p$ unresolved.

Comment: @user2661923 I agree that Faulhaber's formula doesn't answer the question. Note I also didn't state it did. This is why I just prefixed that link with "FYI", with my providing it because I thought it might be of interest as to how to generally express the sum of the powers (i.e., the LHS) in a closed form.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Nice rebuttal.  However, if I was a new Math student, I might have been confused as to what your comment intended.

Comment: Faulhaber's formula may not directly solve the problem, but at least it might help us solve special cases which could lead to a generalization. If we take the case of $p=3$, for example, then we know the sum equals $\frac{N^2(N+1)^2}{4}$. so the question becomes whether this can ever be a cube.

Comment: @L.E. FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%7BN%7Dn%5E%7Bp%7D%3DM%5E%7Bp%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aintegers&p=1) lists the fairly closely related [About the infinite solutions of a Diophantine equation](/q/392345) and [Unique Structure in base for power $1,2$and$3$](/q/3270862).

Comment: Thank you for linking the search method to get to the similar questions. It looks like it was shown there are at most finitely many (p, N) for any p. But no more insight on the structure behind those solutions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to be an open problem.

More general equation has no known non-trivial examples, as described in the article [On the equation $1^k+2^k+\dots+x^k=y^n$](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Akos-Pinter/publication/235417652_On_the_equation_1k2k_xk_yn/links/09e41511619afd456b000000/On-the-equation-1k-2k-xk-yn.pdf), so we cannot reasonably expect to find examples in your special case. By the article it is at least fully resolved for $k \leq 11$.

In the other direction, special case of yours is also well-known [conjecture by Erdős–Moser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Moser_equation) (see also this slightly [newer reference](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/rocky-mountain-journal-of-mathematics/volume-43/issue-5/Mosers-mathemagical-work-on-the-equation-1k2kcdotsm-1kmk/10.1216/RMJ-2013-43-5-1707.full)), it is unknown if $1^k+2^k+\dots+(m-1)^k=m^k$ has other solutions than $1^1+2^1=3^1$. So we cannot reasonably expect to find impossibility proof of your case (as it would prove the above conjecture).

Both of the above problems are also discussed in Richard Guy's *Unsolved Problems in Number Theory* under **D7 Sum of consecutive powers made a power**.

On a more positive note, there are some pretty smart people around, so maybe someone can find something new. Then however don't forget to claim a progress on (at least one of) the above open problems ;)

Comment: Nice answer (+1). Amazing that the impossibility for $k\le 11$ could be established.